# Finding the part of a side split by an angle bisector in a 30-60-90 triangle.

Tags: geometry

Given: △ABC, m∠C=90°, m∠ABC=30°, AL - ∠ bisector, CL=6 ft. 
Find: LB

Here is a picture:

[image]

What I did:

I made $LB=x$. Then I can see that $CL$ is $6$, $CB$ as a whole is $x+6$. Since $∠ABC=30$, I can see in a $30-60-90$ triangle, $CB$ would be the $b$ side. I make $CA=y$ so $CB = {y\sqrt{3} \over 2}$. This would make $CB$, which is also $x+6$, $4\sqrt{3}$ $+2x\sqrt{3} \over 2$. Then since this is a $30-60-90$ triangle, we can use the Pythagorean Theorem, make the equation $$(\frac{y\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+(y)^2=(2y)^2\ where \ y=4\sqrt{3} +2x\sqrt{3}$$ I stop at this because when I substitute this $y$ in, I get a jibberish radical answer. Do I just need to solve some more or should am I looking at this problem completely wrong. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Comment: No, but I think I might have got an answer. AC:AB = 1:2, since it is a 30-60-90 triangle, so CL:LB = 1:2 so LB should be equal to 12?

Comment: That's it! Now, put your solution into an answer so that we can upvote it. :)

Comment: I just found an easier way. Since $AL$ is an angle bisector, The measure of angle ALB is $30$ and the measure of angle ABL is $30$. So, triangle $ALB$ is isosceles so $$AL=LB=6$$ because of $AL = 6$ because of the side opposite to the 30-degree angle theorem in a 30-60-90 triangle.

Comment: I overthought the question. I guess it was pretty easy.